# Calling docker-compose with ssh-agent

Tags: git, docker, github, ssh, docker-compose

I am trying to run a docker-compose application and build from a private GitHub repository.

```
version: '3'

services:
    my-awesome-app:
        build: git@github.com:Tarocco/my-awesome-app.git:development
    # TODO
```

When I clone it manually, it works as expected:

```
# ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/app_git_rsa && git clone git@github.com:Tarocco/my-awesome-app.git'
Identity added: /root/.ssh/app_git_rsa (/root/.ssh/app_git_rsa)
Cloning into 'my-awesome-app'...
remote: Counting objects: 68, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
remote: Total 68 (delta 4), reused 67 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (68/68), 310.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4/4), done.
```

But when I run the following (part of a pull hook script), I expect my GitHub deploy key to allow docker-compose and docker to access my private repository:

```
# ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/app_git_rsa && docker-compose build && docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d'
Identity added: /root/.ssh/app_git_rsa (/root/.ssh/app_git_rsa)
Building my-awesome-app
ERROR: error fetching: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
: exit status 128
```

Instead I just get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can now use an experimental feature, forwarding SSH client connections to the host OS. Please see: * https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/
* https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds

Answer (score 1):

First, double-check how/if the private key was correctly copied in your image `/root/.ssh` folder (with the proper right, `chmod 600`).

You can in your script add a ssh -Tv git@github.com to check that you are correctly authenticated by GitHub.

Since app_git_rsa is *not* the default anme for an SSH key, check if your local root account (outside docker, where the clone is working) has a `/root/.ssh/config` file which does mention which key to use.
If you do, you need to copy that file too in your image (through your `Dockerfile`)